# Selecting a grid item with onClick handlers - ExtJS Grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm have problems selecting the row that's clicked using the handler functions. Currently I'm using

```
            text: 'Edit',
            handler: function() {
                var gridEdit = Ext.getCmp('my_grid').store;
                var name = prompt("Rename " + "'" + textbody + "'" + "?", "Enter name here");
                gridEdit.getAt(0).data.company = name;
                Ext.getCmp('my_grid').getView().refresh();
            }
```

What could I replace getAt(0) with to select the row that's clicked on?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask the selection model for the selected record/s.

```
var rec = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0]
rec.set('company', name);
```

As a side note, **do not** set the data property on the model directly, you need to use the method call so it can update relevant parties when something changes. If you use `set`, there's no reason to call `refresh`, it will all just happen automatically.